# Has there been any research on the stability of buckminsterfullerene?

Tags: molecular-modeling, quantum-chemistry, nanostructures

C60 can refer to any substance composed of molecules with 60 carbon atoms. Buckminsterfullerene on the other hand is specifically the substance composed of soccer ball shape molecules with 60 carbon atoms arranged in a face centered cubic arrangement. According to my question [How ductile is C60?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1473/how-ductile-is-c60), if buckminsterfullerene can keep being pulled thinner and thinner like gold, it might be a really good structural material. However, if it's not chemically stable, there is no use in using it even if it can keep being pulled thinner and thinner like gold. So my question is:

**Has it been proven that buckminsterfullerene is stable?**

Comment: Buckyballs have been synthetically realized and are indeed stable (in that they don't just spontaneously collapse, for instance). Also, check out endohedral fullerenes for different types of buckyballs with guest species in the cage. Regardless, I'm voting to close this question because it does not involve modeling, just like the [prior question](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1473/how-ductile-is-c60) you asked on bucykballs.

Comment: Also, a complete aside, but you're looking for someone to provide a satisfactory answer to your question when you yourself don't know what kind of answer will satisfy you? That is a recipe for disappointment, and you should rethink what you are trying to gain from your post here.

Comment: This SE is specifically for questions about modeling of atomic systems (atomic, micro, or macroscopic).  While this question could be answered with modeling results, you are looking for answers and not attempting to model it yourself.  For this reason I am voting to close, this question would be better suited for the Chemistry or maybe Physics SE.  A basic google search about these materials would give you some of the answers you are asking for, even without access to journal papers.

Comment: One question per question please. I removed the second one and answered the first one :)

Comment: @NikeDattani I guess I had the habits because sometimes it suits to ask 2 questions in a single question. Also, I think it would be helpful to know why this question was closed even after it was fixed up if it got closed after it got fixed up. Maybe it got closed before it got fixed up. Maybe it needs to be clearer what my question is. I'm trying to make it clear what the question is and that the rest is explaining a reason it may be worth while that researchers could later use the answer to invest in new research. The question is whether there is already existing research.

Comment: My answer was downvoted immediately after I improved your question and answered it, despite the answer correctly addressing the question with references and getting 3 upvotes, so perhaps some of the early close-voters do not really care that the question changed. Andrew & Tristan gave their close-vote reasons already, I asked mykd why they close-voted here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113019/general-chat-room-for-matter-modeling-meta, and asked Tyberius here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110431/ask-a-moderator. AloneProgrammer hasn't written anything since July 28 so we might

Comment: not hear from him. I still do not see the benefit of closing an on-topic question that already has a good answer. If you agree with me, perhaps you can write a comment on my answer here: https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/222/5 (but I advise you to keep it short: a lot of your writing here has been long, and this causes the most valuable points you have to get "lost" from some readers). Tyberius hammered open the question in that Meta post, and if he's to remain consistent he'll have to re-open this one too, but he's not answering in the Ask a Moderator chat room: so try harder!

Answer (score 5):

> "Has there been any research on the stability of buckminsterfullerene?"

There is, for example, this paper with title ["Stability of Buckminsterfullerene, C60"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0009261403017883). It has almost 100 citations.

> "Has it been proven that buckminsterfullerene is stable?"

Stable buckyballs have been made experimentally, and they were also predicted theoretically [as far back as the 1960s](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fullerene#History).

They are one of the most stable compounds known of that size, and form with an icosohedral symmetry.

Comment: Indeed there were multiple papers with soot analysis - the largest peak in the mass spectra was at 720 Daltons = C60. In other words - among all possible particles, C60 was the most prevalent due to the high stability.